# Ansible sudo error while building on Atlas

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, ansible, provisioning

I've been trying to build my Vagrant configuration on Atlas. Also I'm using ansible for provisioning and i have some sudo issues.

After setting up VM while trying to run ansible playbook on Atlas I get this error:

```
virtualbox-iso: failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "item": ""}
virtualbox-iso: msg: Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation
```

So I've found on internet that sudo permissions may be the issue.
In my main playbook file permissions are set to:

```
sudo: true
remote_user: vagrant
```

And the whole thing breakes righ after running playbook, when I need sudo permission, on this cmd in playbook:

```
-name: Update apt
sudo: yes
apt: update_cache=yes
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this situation ? How do I fix sudo permissions on ansible ?

NOTE.
When I'm trying to build this machine locally it works like a charm but when I run it on Atlas I get the issue.

UPDATE:
I believe that sudo access is real issue here I've removed that part of config and it keeps failing on other parts that require sudo.

```
virtualbox-iso: failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=curl,wget,python-software-  properties) => {"failed": true, "item": "curl,wget,python-software-properties"}
 virtualbox-iso: stderr: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
virtualbox-iso: E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: What is atlas in this context ?

Comment: @lian Atlas is product from Hasicorp ecosystem for building VMs online, just push config to it and it creates VM, in theory :)

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation` means that some other application is holding the apt lock. Maybe there is some other install process running on the system?

Check `ps aux | grep apt` output for suspicious processes.

The error message could also be caused by insufficient privileges. You might want to check if the Ansible user gets full root access via sudo. To check that open the sudoers on the host with `visudo`. You should have a line like

`ansible_user        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, if empty it probably can be removed

Comment: lock files are usually empty. Maybe some othe apt process did not delete the lock file properly after finishing. Does `ps aux` not list any suspicious processes?

Comment: I believe that sudo access is real issue here I've removed that part of config and it keeps failing on other parts that require sudo

Comment: Failed to lock can also result from insufficient privilege.

Comment: Then we have a winner :(